# package json not found

Tags: raspbian, pi-zero-w

I've been trying to fix this for a few hours and still can't make it work. pls help me....

```
pi@Yang:~ $  sudo npm install
npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies
npm ERR! Linux 4.9.41+
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.2.1
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.7
npm ERR! path /home/pi/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOPACKAGEJSON
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! package.json ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/pi/package.json'
npm ERR! package.json This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! package.json npm can't find a package.json file in your current directory.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/pi/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: what is in **/home/pi/npm-debug.log**

Comment: oh it's just a log file

Comment: try `sudo apt-get install nodejs npm node-semver `

Comment: yup i've tried that still package.json npm can't find a package.json file in your current directory

Comment: what is the package you are trying to install? or are you just trying to install npm?

Comment: im trying to install sudo but it says package.json  cant be found, if that answers your question

Answer (score 1):

NPM Comes installed with Node so check if your installed already

```
npm -v
```

and if not installed then install

```
sudo apt-get install npm
```

---

. But I think your problem is you are either:

## 1. Running from /home/pi/

which is not a node app root directory, so cd into a node app then run

```
sudo npm install
```

## 2. Install *packagename* without an app using -g for global namespace

```
npm install -g packagename
```